# Can Mathematica Find Closed-Form Solution this Equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have tries to solve an equation by using Solve[] to find pl as a function of other variables. However, it generates an Error! Can anyone help?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear[temp]
temp = Solve[(((1 - pi)*(pl - ph)/(1 - ph))^((1 - 
           pi)*λl))*((pi*(pl - ph)/(pl - 1))^(pi)) == ((pi*(pl - ph)*
         R/(ph*(pl - 1)))^(pi*(1 - λh)))*(((pl - 
           ph)*(pi*λh + λl - 
            pi*λl)/(λh*(pl - 1) + λl*(1 - 
               ph)))^(pi*λh + λl - pi*λl)) && 0 <= pi <= 1 && 
   0 <= λh <= 1 && 0 <= λl <= 1 && 1 <= R <= 2 && 0 <= ph <= 1 && 
   1 <= pl <= 2, {pl}]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

```
(* input returned unevaluated *)
```

Comment: On the face of it, it is not an error that is generated, but an answer to your question.  Still, that is not necessarily a reason to give up....Try a special case of your parameters, maybe, just to test a simpler equation.

Comment: One solution to this appears near where many parts of the equation are approaching 0/0 or 0^0.

Comment: Did you have any good reason to believe your complicated equation is supposed to have a closed form solution?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. As I am quite new to Mathematica, any comments are appreciated. The reason I think it might be a closed form solution is that the powers of those terms in the equation are less than two given constraints I put. However, if they are not integer, I am not sure if the solution exists.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/496229?p_p_auth=EXNODw3z

Comment: Do you mean that some of the parameters are meant to be integers?  The way your code is written, they will be assumed to be real numbers, which is why it (probably) can't be solved.  Which are integers?

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. My parameters are positive real and the powers of each term are positive real between 0-2. I am not sure that in this case there will be any way to find to solution of the system as I need it badly : (

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.